# Python program to get output as nested dictionary counts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the file in the format below

```
Pid,Lid
2000,150
2000,450
2000,300
2000,150
3000,100
3000,250
3000,100
```

Desired Output

```
{'2000':{'150':2,'300':1,'450':1},'3000':{'100':2,'250':1}}
```

For each Pid, I am building a dictionary with Pid as key and a nested dictionary as value. This nested dictionary has Lid as key and its frequency as value.

```
frequency={}
for eachline in file:
    eachline =eachline .strip()
    Pid,Lid = eachline .split(',')
    if Pid in frequency:
        frequency[Pid][Lid]=frequency[Pid][Lid]+1
    else:
        frequency[Pid]={Lid :1}
print frequency
```

This is code I am trying but it does not work, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store the counts, and read the *.csv* file with with [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

# create nested defaultdicts
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

# open file with context manager
with open('pids.csv') as f:

    # create csv reader object
    csv_reader = reader(f)

    # skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    # collect counts
    for pid, lid in csv_reader:
        d[pid][lid] = d[pid].get(lid, 0) + 1

pprint(d)
```

Which gives the following:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fcf5b8a7f28>,
            {'2000': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                             {'150': 2,
                              '300': 1,
                              '450': 1}),
             '3000': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'100': 2, '250': 1})})
```

You could also count with a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the sub dictionary:

```
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

# create defaultdict of Counters
d = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())

# open file with context manager
with open('pids.csv') as f:

    # create csv reader object
    csv_reader = reader(f)

    # skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    # collect counts
    for pid, lid in csv_reader:
        d[pid][lid] += 1

pprint(d)
```

Which gives the following:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f2b024b7f28>,
            {'2000': Counter({'150': 2, '450': 1, '300': 1}),
             '3000': Counter({'100': 2, '250': 1})})
```

**Note:** `defaultdict()` and `Counter()` are just subclasses of `dict`, meaning that they can be treated as normal dictionaries.